# run project tests from azure devops pipeline

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a solution with a project in VS2022 with some unit tests.

To run the tests locally I just right click on the project and choose 'Run Tests'.

Any idea how can I do this in Azure Devops Pipeline?

[Running tests from context menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lRyP.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

It's going to depend whether or not your project is an SDK-styled project or not. If you don't know what that is, if you are targeting .NET 5 (as well as .NETCoreApp 3.0) or higher then it is.

If it is *not* an SDK styled project, then you will need to use the [VSTest@2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/vstest?view=azure-devops) task in your yaml pipeline.

If it is, then you just use then [DotNetCoreCLI@2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli?view=azure-devops) task to run tests.